# Curves in $\mathbb R^n$ and boundary points

Tags: general-topology, analysis, curves

Thinking of a curve as a 1-dimensional continuum, intuitively one would think that a curve can never have this property. Perhaps intuition is correct and this question is somewhat naive, but here it is anyway:

> Can we find a curve or trajectory $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ such that there is at least one point on the curve that is not a boundary point (under the Euclidean topology)? Infinitely many such points? The entirety of the curve?

I feel that such a curve would probably have a fractal construction in some sense, but I can't fathom what it would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not? Check out [space-filling curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve). Such a beast is a continuous, surjective function $[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$. Since the function is surjective, no point in the preimage of the interior of the unit square will map to a boundary point of the image in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Here's a gif animating the first several iterations of Hilbert's construction of such a curve.
[image: Hilbert curve. Source: Wikipedia.]

The reason your intuition is wrong is that your repertoire of examples is filled with *differentiable* functions, not arbitrary *continuous* functions. In fact, differentiability is an incredible constraint on how a curve can behave. If your function is differentiable at a point, that means as you zoom in, there's only one direction, one speed it can be going: The direction and speed of the derivative. 
But there are *so many* other directions it *could* go at that point if it were merely continuous, not differentiable.

An arbitrary continuous curve is not differentiable; it displays "fractal" behavior, in the sense that no matter how far you zoom, it will be jagged. This can be made precise in a couple of different ways, but the gist is that almost every continuous function is nowhere differentiable.

Comment: The space-filling curve is fascinating - exactly what I was looking for.